# How to change attribute for the dropdown item in select2 jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2, selector

How can I get all dropdown items in selector2?

I have few selectors with the same options, and on selecting, I want to change attributes for those items in all selectors. But I can't get them on the select event. I'm talking about the aria-selected attribute, when I'm choosing an option in that selector this attribute is changing, but  I need to change it also in other selectors. For this, I want to get items with a specific class and change the attribute for them with jquery.

How can I do it, or is there a better way for doing it?

[image]

Comment: Plese show html as text and relevant js/jquery code .

Comment: without a sample showing your problem and what you want, it will be difficult to help you

Comment: thanks guys, I figured it out, it was my mistake